# How to resize fixed background image in mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background image fixed banner to my site.
The code I used is
html

```
<div class="section-1 box text-center">
      <h1>WELCOME TO CAR ARENA</h1>
      <p><i>THE BEST CAR ACESSORIES ONLINE CART IN KERALA</i></p>
    </div>
```

css

```
.section-1 {
 z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/car.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

But In mobile mode it not works properly. See my site [here](https://cararenashop.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the size to `background-size: cover;` instead. That will make the image take up the space it needs for its ratio. It will not have the effect as you have on desktop as the image is wider then taller.

```
.section-1 {
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(../images/car.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I would recommend that you have specific image adjusted for mobile use, that means make it narrow and taller, then you can use it like this.

```
.section-1 {
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(../images/car-mobile.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  background-image: url(../images/car.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: What should be the dimension of image adjusted for mobile device?

Comment: @JustineChacko depends on how much you want it to take up? Lets say for a mobile device only and full screen I would go with 380px wide and 820px for height.

Comment: Still I don't get text scrolling over image effect in mobile

Comment: @JustineChacko as I can see it works with scrolling. I noticed that you had `background-size: 100% 100%;`, that is not the solution to your problem, there is no aspect ratio in that image what so ever in that approach. I'm sorry, but, it does not look good.

Comment: In your answer there is `background-size:100%`. Also scrolling works with Android Firefox but not with Android chrome. I use updated chrome. Is this a cache or history issue?

Comment: @JustineChacko My bad that was a miss, it should be like the first example there, either way I changed it to reflect it. Just to be clear on the scrolling issue as I don't have a Android to test on. What happens and how does it look?

Comment: I tested your code in console, it works, **but** when I close console(which will result increase the height of the page), then image goes out of the screen. You can also see that I think.

Comment: @JustineChacko You can have specific background-size for desktop and mobile, check my updated answer. `cover` will cover the background and make use of the image size, `contain` will respect the size of the container and make it as wide as the container and at the same time keep the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 0):

you should use extra code for the mobile and tablet formats with @media. There I would recommend you to play with width and remember to use the display:flex and other responsive attributes.

I will link you a useful link from W3C 
[mediaqueries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Hi, Welcome Eloisa. This is not a helping answer for this case I would say. Does not address the issue OP has.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this. And according to the first answer, use mediaqueries to make it not only work properly but also look good on mobile devices.

```css
.section-1 {
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; // make sure your image remain centered
    background-image: url(../images/car.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `background-size: 100% 100%;` using media query for mobile case for your height

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .section-1 {
       background-size: 100% 100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: this will just stretch the image

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .section-1 {
         background-size: cover; 
         background-position: bottom;
    }
    .box{
        display:block;
    }
}
```